# What does the number of votes received include, on a Stack Exchange 2.0 meta site?

Tags: support, per-site-meta

On Stack Exchange 2.0 meta site, where the users don't gain reputation (or that reputation is hidden), the user drop-down menu reports the number of votes received from the user, instead of showing the reputation.

[image: screenshot]

Does the number of votes include the votes given on Community Wiki posts, or does it include only the votes that would give reputation?

Comment: This question didn't really get enough attention. I might put up a bounty.